# PHP/Drupal Web Application crashes on Azure Web Apps

Tags: php, fastcgi, azure-web-app-service

We have hosted application on azure web apps and its continuously crashing due to some issue (might be configuration) - Below is description. We detected Application crashes during this timeframe.

**Description:** We detected crashes in your application .

**Next Steps:** Please check the event logs table below to see if there are any uncaught exceptions might be causing this. Also, you can check out useful Links section to explore some of the other options that can help diagnose crashes in your application.

**Exception Code:** 142 crashes due to (0xE0434352 - CLR Exception)

[image]

Comment: And what have you tried to debug this? As the screenshot tells you: have a look at the log files

Answer (score 0):

This issues is usually because of the  worker runtime setting

```
Mismatched worker runtime setting - (0xE0434352 - CLR Exception) function internal server error
```

I has this issue once. As it turned out was `FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME` in application settings set to `dotnet`, although I am quite sure that I opted for `javascript`. Correcting the value to "`node`" solved the problem.

Please ensure in your web app , you runtime is correctly set.

Please refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-php-configure) link for configuring php app in azure.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply Mohit. Can you please elaborate more , with screenshots if possible or detailed steps

Comment: with the above change no luck

Comment: Have you tried to follow article while deploying your php app which I mentioned in the answer. Have you enabled the logging in your app ?